# how could I fix this? Can I keep the variable local or do I have to use a global? New to this :D

Tags: python, discord, bots

I am trying to get the bot to recognize a Discord ID when the keyword "IGC RECEIPT" is used in a message that also lists the Discord ID for that user. Then, it should DM the user with the found Discord ID saying "Hello! [Discord ID]" However, I don't know how to get past the `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'discord_id' referenced before assignment`.

```
import discord 
import os

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def  GetValueFromString(content, startMarker, endMarker):
            StartPos = content.index(startMarker) + startMarker.len()
            EndPos = content.index(endMarker)
             return content[StartPos: EndPos]
           
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
     return

    if message.content.startswith('IGC RECEIPT'):
      discord_id = GetValueFromString(message, 'discordid: ', 'start: ')
    dm = await message.author.create_dm()
    await dm.send(message.author,'Hello! ' +discord_id)


  my_secret = os.environ['BOT TOKEN']
  client.run(my_secret)
```

```
2022-10-13 23:13:39 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
2022-10-13 23:13:40 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: c3e2f0f10a911f485c487565a753a826).
We have logged in as Refund Bot#6273
2022-10-13 23:13:52 ERROR    discord.client Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Refund-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 24, in on_message
    await dm.send(message.author,'Hello! ' +discord_id)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'discord_id' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I recommend the [tour] and [ask]. I've added backticks to format your code, but the line numbers (and that nonsemantic `strong`—copied from a web interface?) make this impossible to copy, paste, and run. Please copy your code in a useable form, include the full error message and stack trace, and if possible, remove any details unrelated to the bug. (See [MRE].) Also your indentation varies, from one space to eleven. Four is the standard, and will make your code easier to read.

Comment: Everyone starts somewhere. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: In the `if` of line 21, in the end, you can make an `else` and then do something like `return`